# When might you prefer a Synchronous Producer over an Asynchronous Producer in production?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to wrap my head around when you might prefer to use a Synchronous Producer over an Asynchronous Producer in production. It seems to me that it's almost always preferable to use an Async Producer simply because of the gains in performance, but there must be some strong use cases for a Synchronous Producer as well. There is some subjectivity here, but I am just trying to understand some different contexts for when you may want to utilize each.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much never.

There is actually no such thing as a synchronous Kafka producer. Every implementation of [`send()`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-) is asynchronous and returns a java `Future`.

Behind the scene, each invocation of `send()` is just filling a local buffer which gets sent to the broker later on at the client's discretion, either when it's full or after some timeout (both configurable). Only after the result of that transmission is known do the `Future` terminate and tell us how it went.

The only way to mimic a synchronous behavior on the producer side would be to block on that `Future` with `get()`, which defeats all the throughput and compression benefits of the buffering and typically hurts scalability of the application itself due to blocking behavior and resource contention.

The only case when that *could* be useful in prod is when you absolutely need to make sure that that specific record is acknowledged to be in Kafka before moving on and some other technology in your project prevents you from doing that in a non-blocking way, but that's a serious bad smell IMHO.

Or maybe if you really don't care about performance nor scalability for that specific use case and prefer the apparent simplicity of blocking code, but then probably Kafka is not the most appropriate technology, since the only justification for enduring the limitations of the Kafka API is to achieve high scalability and throughput.

Explicit usage  of the blocking behavior of `flush()` can sometimes be more understandable IMHO. That one can be useful when we receive a bunch of input values (for example, a batch of 1000 messages from AWS Kinesis received in one single invocation of an AWS lambda) that needs to be sent reliably to Kafka before exiting. We can then do 1000 asynchronous `send()` calls, then block on `flush()` and only leave the lambda with success or failure depending on how the Kafka acknowledgments went

Or sometimes in unit tests with a local TestContainer we need to `flush()` all the test data before running the tested logic.